# Random error: System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have been getting this error in my C# app:

> System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No process is on the other end of the pipe

The strange part though, is that it only occurs sometimes.  I can never seem to reproduce it, and its very random.  The userid/password in the connection string is correct, and I haven't messed with any of the SQL server configuration settings.  I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.0.

Comment: When this happens do you have to restart SQL server? Or restart something? Check on process manager to see if the server falls over.

Comment: @LewsTherin No, the second attempt will work fine.